# Setup for enhancing the C language using mbeddr and mps

Tags: c, dsl, mps

I'm trying to write some new statements for an internal C DSL.
The tool of my choice is [MPS](http://www.jetbrains.com/mps/index.html) and the base is the c-core of [mbeddr](http://mbeddr.com/). 
I found [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H3UMKp99p3w) tutorial on the internet. Since it is a little old, I am not able to duplicate the exact structure of the setup itself.

What I want to do is to create a new language. This language must be extended by com.mbeddr.core. I found, how to extend the language and did so. I needed to extend every single language com.mbeddr.core.* by its own, everything else did not work (it does not even work properly now).

The I created a new statement in a structure module. There I extended the concept to a Statement (c.m.c.statements.structure is shown). Then, following the video tutorial, I wanted to add an expression as a child, this is where it fails.

I am not sure where I went wrong here. It is very difficult to set it up properly, since all tutorials/guides are outdated.

Thanks for your help,

Best Simon

Comment: You should help people help you.  You need to provide links to `mbeddr` and `MPS` ([MPS?](http://www.jetbrains.com/mps/index.html)).  You should also show the code that you've tried because there's no way anyone can guess what you've done wrong without seeing your code.  See also [Is MPS (a meta-programming language) worth looking into?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177536/is-mps-a-meta-programming-language-worth-looking-into)

Comment: For a reference to `mbeddr` (and MPS), see [What are the extensible languages people are using today?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924363/what-are-the-extensible-languages-people-are-using-today/16524989#16524989).

Comment: Thank you for your appropriate critique. I revised my question and added the references to the text. Concerning my code, there is not much to add. MPS is a GUI based development suite, generating most of the content. I did not change anything, compared to the video. People working with MPS will hopefully understand what I mean.